# Meaning of legend value in Kernel Density?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

I have done some analyses on the spatial distribution of traffic signs using kernel density, I used SQUARE_KILOMETERS in area unit, the output is good and clear, but I don't understand the meaning of the legend.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please, specify 'some analysis' in detail; i.e, explain what your data is, what did you do, and what you want to do. Give some context for your question and explain better your data and how you did the analysis. Tks.

Answer (score -1):

If you ran the Kernel Density tool then you must have set the population field, even if you set it to None it treats each point as 1. It clearly states this in the [syntax section of the help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm#GUID-2A9F4A90-3920-403F-895D-BA8DB36EC826). As you do not describe how you ran the tool as hinted by @Andre_Silva we can only assume you did not set this. So the values in the legend would be the number of points per square kilometre within the search radius that you set or... did not set?

All your questions will be answered if you study the help file of this tool, there is even an expanded section on how it calculates the values via link under the summary section.

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd, the values in the legend meaning the number of points per square kilometer within the search radius 100 meters.